# Time trend in panel data

Tags: panel-data

I found one paper where they have used panel of 50 countries over 15 years. While describing the model they have mentioned that they have used **time invariant country fixed effect and a time trend common to all countries**.Can you please explain what does that mean?

Comment: This is not on-topic for the site. You just do `xtreg` and put your fixed effect as one of the `xi` effects. The regression doesn't care whether the covariate is time varying or not, all that matters is how it shows  up in the dataset.